# rspec - customised route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have simplified an issue I am having to the following

I have a route that looks like this

```
namespace :client do
  resources :thing, :only => [:index]
end
```

and the simple rspec test

```
describe Client::ThingController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

However what I'd like to do is alter the url I use to access the resource from

```
/client/thing.json
```

to

```
/api/client/v1/thing.json
```

1) How do I update my routes and rspec?

If I then wanted to parameterise the uri such that I could extract the api_version

```
/api/client/[api_version]/thing.json
```

2) How would this effect my routes and simple rspec test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd previously tried what @Mori had suggested before I had posted but without having the multiple routes as proposed, I should have mentioned that in the original post.

What I eventually got that worked is:

1) In `routes.rb` I added

```
match "api/client/:api_version/thing" => 'client/thing#index'
```

*NOTE: The missing leading '/' ie `match "/api/...` => `match "api/...` it seems to make all the difference to `rspec`.*

2) And in my rspec `thing_controller_spec.rb` I now have this

```
describe Client::ThingController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'index', :api_version => 'v1'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

I was close before but it was the leading '/' in `routes.rb` that broke me even though I could navigate to the url in a browser.